# jQuery .toggle(showOrHide): implementation question

Tags: show-hide, jquery

I'm having a button toggle whether a referenced div is visible or not.  Originally, I was using the code:

```
$('#search-options-btn').click(function() {
    if ($('#search-options').is('.hidden')) {
        $('#search-options').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#search-options').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

However, in an attempt to find cleaner code, I came across the jQuery `toggle()` method, which according to the API has a method implementation

```
.toggle( showOrHide )    
showOrHide: A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.
```

This description leads me to believe this is a shortcut implementation method for showing or hiding by passing the...identifier? `showOrHide` into the `toggle()` method.

Of course, attempting this:

```
$('#search-options-btn').click(function() {
    $('#search-options').toggle(showOrHide);
});
```

yields an error in my firebug console:

```
showOrHide is not defined
[Break On This Error] $('#search-options').toggle(showOrHide);
```

I've also tried defining `showOrHide` as a boolean initialized to `false`; the error goes away, but the issue is not fixed.

According to the jQuery online API, this is supposed to be equivalent to

```
if ( showOrHide == true ) {
  $('#foo').show();
} else if ( showOrHide == false ) {
  $('#foo').hide();
}
```

unless I'm completely missing how this works.  Can anyone fill me in on what I'm doing wrong here? I haven't been able to find a similar implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should just need toggle(), nothing else.

`$('#search-options-btn').click(function() {
    $('#search-options').toggle();
});`

Answer (score 0):

showOrHide is the internal name.  You pass in a bool:

```
$('#...').showOrHide(true)
```

if you want the item to be visible, `false` if you want it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Its just toggle between class and not with boolean..

```
$('#search-options-btn').click(function() { $('#search-options').toggle('yourClassName'); });
```

If **yourClassName** is found, then it will remove the same, otherwise it will add it.

Comment: No, you're thinking of the `.toggleClass()` method. The `.toggle()` method _does_ (optionally) accept a boolean.